# Close reason: belongs on another SE site, only Engineering Meta available?

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, close-reasons

I believe [this question](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6306/does-elevator-passengers-wait-time-depend-on-floor) belongs on Maths.SE. I therefore voted to close, and selected "this belongs on another SE site", and clicked Next. My only option then was to select that it belonged on Meta.Engineering.SE. Which it doesn't. So I had to go back and select a different close reason.

Is this just a rep thing that I can't state which SE site it belongs on? Or is there something else going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, not just a rep thing.

Currently, the Engineering site is in beta.  As such, we don't have any defined migration paths set up.

Once we graduate, the community needs to decide which site(s) we ought to have defined migration paths set up for.  Off-hand, I'd think that Electrical (Electronics?) Engineering, Mathematics, and Physics would be candidates for us to consider.

But until we graduate, you ought to flag the question and patiently wait for your kind hearted janitorial staff to handle the flag.  And don't worry about the question already having been closed.  The site mods can re-open and then close with a migrate easily enough.

Normally, we're handling flags within 2 - 3 hours on average.  I suspect that because today is Thanksgiving in the US and all the mods are US based that we're a bit behind on keeping up with our janitorial duties.  Sorry about that.

Comment: And FWIW, I have just migrated the question over to Mathematics.

Comment: Cheers Glen. Yourself and the other mods are very much appreciated; and feel free to take Thanksgiving off!

Answer (score 2):

Only a few pre-defined migration pathways can be set. And there have to be a lot of questions taking that route to justify a pre-set migration pathway. If you want to migrate a question elsewhere, just vote to close it as off-topic, not about engineering; then flag a moderator proposing a migration elsewhere.

(that's how I think it should be done - but a mod may be along shortly with a definitive answer)