# Adding EE and Home Improvement options to "belongs in another stack" close?

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

There is a "belongs in another stack" close category, but it only has one option defined here, "Meta", which seems to be a rare offender.

Do moderators (or anyone) have the ability to add to that option list?

I would think the EE and DIY/Home-Improvement are the most common "misplaced questions" for this stack.

Cheers!

Comment: nevermind, realized it's already [answered](https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/401/close-reason-belongs-on-another-se-site-only-engineering-meta-available?rq=1)

Comment: The answer that you found is correct. You can't do it yourself, so just flag it for a moderator to take care of.